# Purpose of Decrypting & Scanning HTTPS traffic

Tags: certificate-authority, firewalls, firefox, decryption, pem

Navigating to the below URL link from the Mozilla Firefox and entering some website link and clicking on View, displays certificate Viewer

```
chrome://pippki/content/exceptionDialog.xul
```

[image]
[image]

After enabling Decrypt & scan HTTPS traffic from the firewall rule, all the clients cannot go to www because they don’t have SSL CA Certificate.

So they have included the **`SecurityAppliance_SSL_CA`** (.pem format) and installed on to the client machines from the **Microsoft Management Console (MMC)** i.e, from the Trusted Root **`Certification Authorities > Certificates`**. Performing Import *.pem file

And also included a private key specific to the static IP address identified unique specifying the Friendly Name to be **SSIS Master Service**

It's very clear that they are not using any proxy server.

Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue. Because
Peer’s Certificate issuer is not recognized.

> HTTP Strict Transport Security: false
>
> HTTP Public Key Pinning: true

I do own an Anti-Virus software from Sophos Endpoint Security and control for my personal PC, with Web protection enabled. But I don't get any sort of messages from the FireFox

[image]

So my question is what is the purpose of doing this? and Does our passwords gets decrypted in an encrypted websites via MITM decryption or store logs?
Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: are you aware what "Sophos" is as the certificate issuer?

Comment: https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/132997#What%20is%20HTTPS%20Decrypt%20and%20Scan?

Comment: ESET, G-Data,... a lot of AV vendors offer HTTPS interception. How else can they scan your downloads when they pass over HTTPS?

Answer (score 2):

> what is the purpose of doing this?

The antivirus wouldn't be able to detect a virus/exploit that was delivered through https. Breaking the https connection would allow it to detect and block such threat.

> It's very clear that they are not using any proxy server.

No. There may not be a configured proxy server, but the aforementioned firewall is acting as one, apparently in combination with a Sophos instance (this will be a *transparent proxy*).

> Does our passwords gets decrypted in an encrypted websites via MITM decryption

Yes. Anything that goes through the MITM connection will be decrypted and then re-encrypted

> or store logs?

You should ask to the person that configured this system performing a MITM

> Is there any way to get around this?

Disable the "Decrypt & scan HTTPS traffic" rule? It may be possible to configure specific destinations that shall *not* be subject to MITM.

Also, it could be that connecting through a proxy / VPN allowed to bypass this specific security setting. But in this case I don't think it would be appropriate. If you are allowed not to go through this filtering, you should get this rule disabled. If you are not allowed to bypass it, it seems unwise to work around it without authorization.

Comment: Do you think my AV will be able to scan only Non-SSL based website?.
If this XG Firewall alone is configured to scan & decrypt SSL based website. 
In such case, why would some one go for choosing another product of AV installed on all the client's machine.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you they were not using a Regular Proxy, instead Transparent proxy had been detected from the following HTTP headers:
Via `HTTPS/1.1 forward.http.proxy:3128
X_forwarded_for the public IP(xxx.xx.xxx.xx)`

If this product continues to sold as a MOTS, rather than COTS, then they'll be serious threats to our privacy